# How to replace occurance of a string in a variable containing jquery captured html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, replace

I have trouble with replacing certain values in a variable that contains captured html.

I'll let the code explain what I want to accomplish.

lest say:

```
last_id = 1;
data.id = 2;
```

the code:

```
/*prepare new edit,delete button*/
var controls = $('table#option_groups tr:last td:last').html();
```

outputting var controls will return:

```
<a href="stuff/edit/1">Edit</a>
<a href="stuff/delete/1">Delete</a>
```

trying to replace\update edit button:

```
//replacing edit button
controls.replace('/edit/'+last_id, '/edit/'+data.id);
```

outputting controls after replace:

```
<a href="stuff/edit/1">Edit</a>
<a href="stuff/delete/1">Delete</a>
```

desired output:

```
<a href="stuff/edit/2">Edit</a>
<a href="stuff/delete/1">Delete</a>
```

So the question is: How do you replace occurance of string in a varible that contains captured html.

Thank you!

Comment: You just should not do this with html strings. Use the DOM.

Comment: I wouldn't attempt to manipulate the HTML. Find the anchor element you want to update and change it's `href` attribute (e.g.: `$('a.edit').attr('href', 'new href');`).

Comment: I'm planning on doing so - inserting unmodified and modify them in place. I'm just curious at this point, as I thought this should work, apparently I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one line of code:

```
var controls = $('table#option_groups tr:last td:last').html().replace("/edit/"+last_id, "/edit/"+data.id);
```

Output:

```
<a href="stuff/edit/2">Edit</a>
<a href="stuff/delete/1">Delete</a>
```

Comment: here, have an up-vote :) Thank you ...
Edit: sorry no up-vote - up-votes require 15 reputation :]
Edit2: got two rep points, and up-voted.. thanks..

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are not re-assigning replaced string to `controls` variable, try this:

```
controls = controls.replace('/edit/'+last_id, '/edit/'+data.id);
```